# Is GENERATE SERIES quicker than a SUBQUERY?

Tags: sql

I would like to optimize my query, I'm currently sub-querying a table loaded with a sequence of SMALLINT values from 0 to 9999.

[image]

Comment: Benchmark it and see. And which database?

Comment: It's my own home-brew database.

Comment: Maybe you don't understand the database question.  Is it SQL Server or Oracle or MySQL or ...?  We can't give you a performance answer without understanding the database your query is written for.

Comment: It is you who didn't understand my answer!.. This is not SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL or any commercially available RDBMS, its a proprietary RDBMS, not available in the market, it was developed in-house, but why does that matter anyway if all I'm asking is if GENERATE SERIES is faster than a SUBQUERY?.. They're both supported by this database!

Comment: How would we know how to optimize your home-brew database?  We have no idea how you designed it, or what tweaks might improve its performance.  What works well as an optimization on one RDBMS might not work so well on another.

Comment: Let me put it to you this way: Make believe it is Oracle 11g, but with a lot more functionality, or make believe its the database you use. Catcall's answer addresses what I'm looking for, while you're drowning in a glass of water over what database engine it is!.. Did you see me post any tags of SQL-Server, Oracle, etc?.. NO, that's why I just tagged plain vanilla SQL!

Comment: Good for @Catcall.  My crystal ball is out for repair this week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you can tell for sure is to test it.

I did similar tests using PostgreSQL a few months ago. The question was whether it made sense to replace a calendar table with generate_series().

In our case, the table was faster. But if you test, you'll probably find that generate_series() becomes faster at a certain number of rows.  (That's what we found, but the number of rows was well over anything we used.)  My guess is that, at that point, the time it takes to generate the series becomes less than the time it takes to read the index and rows off the disk.

That's a guess, because PostgreSQL's EXPLAIN ANALYZE  doesn't give you much detail about disk I/O.

Comment: I had a very similar situation as your calendar fact table http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616119/date-lookup-table-1990-01-012041-12-31 .. My situation is: I have a fact table with only one small integer(32767) column containing a series from 0 to 9999, and its indexed which is doing a NOT IN subquery to all the numbers which have been drawn (2,820 numbers) in a Pick-4 lottery game, so I'm thinking that using a generate series is quicker than having to open an extra table with 10,000 rows?

Comment: I wouldn't assume your dbms needs to "open a table".  Guessing doesn't scale well, especially with database management systems. That's why they all include some way to see what the query optimizer is doing.  You *should* assume that every NOT IN query will be unable to use an index. Google "sargable expressions". 10000 rows isn't very many; your optimizer might do a sequential scan on that table even when it *could* use an index.

Comment: our SET EXPLAIN ON is also another area where we don't get much explanation of whats going on. Although our query optimizer is cost-based, explain doesn't tell us things like: disk I/O's, CPU usage, chose to use table scan vs. index, etc. I usually do a safe-boot so as to minimize other processes and use WINDOWS task manager performance analyzer or UNIX's "sar" (system activity report) to see what's going on. My past experience is a subquery which has to scan thru a table containing 10,000 rows which are evaluated with a NOT IN, equivalent to OR's is more expensive than doing NOT IN (1,2,3...)