# in sql, calculating date parts versus date lookup table in group queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

many queries are by week, month or quarter when the base table date is either `date` or `timestamp`.

in general, in `group by` queries, does it matter whether using
 - functions on the date
 - a `day` table that has extraction pre-calculated

note: similar question as [DATE lookup table (1990/01/01:2041/12/31)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616119/date-lookup-table-1990-01-012041-12-31)

for example, in `postgresql`

```
create table sale(
  tran_id   serial       primary key,
  tran_dt   date         not null default current_date,
  sale_amt  decimal(8,2) not null,
  ...
);

create table days(
  day       date      primary key,
  week      date      not null,
  month     date      not null,
  quarter   date      non null
);

-- week query 1: group using funcs
select
  date_trunc('week',tran_dt)::date - 1 as week,
  count(1) as sale_ct,
  sum(sale_amt) as sale_amt
from sale
where date_trunc('week',tran_dt)::date - 1 between '2012-1-1' and '2011-12-31'
group by date_trunc('week',tran_dt)::date - 1
order by 1;

-- query 2: group using days
select
  days.week,
  count(1) as sale_ct,
  sum(sale_amt) as sale_amt
from sale
join days on( days.day = sale.tran_dt )
where week between '2011-1-1'::date and '2011-12-31'::date
group by week
order by week;
```

to me, whereas the `date_trunc()` function seems more organic, the the `days` table is easier to use.

is there anything here more than a matter of taste?

Comment: You can create an index on the expression `date_trunc('week',tran_dt)::date` to speed things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-- query 3: group using instant "immediate" calendar table
WITH calender AS (
        SELECT  ser::date AS dd
        , date_trunc('week', ser)::date AS wk
        -- , date_trunc('month', ser)::date AS mon
        -- , date_trunc('quarter', ser)::date AS qq
        FROM generate_series( '2012-1-1' , '2012-12-31', '1 day'::interval) ser
        )
SELECT
  cal.wk
  , count(1) as sale_ct
  , sum(sa.sale_amt) as sale_amt
FROM sale sa
JOIN calender cal ON cal.dd = sa.tran_dt
-- WHERE week between '2012-1-1' and '2011-12-31'
GROUP BY cal.wk
ORDER BY cal.wk
        ;
```

Note: I fixed an apparent typo in the BETWEEN range.

UPDATE: I used Erwin's recursive CTE to squeeze out the duplicated date_trunc(). Nested CTE galore:

```
WITH calendar AS (
        WITH RECURSIVE montag AS (
        SELECT '2011-01-01'::date  AS dd
        UNION ALL
        SELECT dd + 1 AS dd
        FROM   montag
        WHERE  dd < '2012-1-1'::date
        )
    SELECT mo.dd, date_trunc('week', mo.dd + 1)::date AS wk
    FROM montag mo
    )
SELECT
  cal.wk
  , count(1) as sale_ct
  , sum(sa.sale_amt) as sale_amt
FROM sale sa
JOIN calendar cal ON cal.dd = sa.tran_dt
-- WHERE week between '2012-1-1' and '2011-12-31'
GROUP BY cal.wk
ORDER BY cal.wk
        ;
```

Comment: Pretty much the query I was going to use as example in my answer. :)

Comment: Is is also a clean way to express the *restrict* part of the query. Maybe you could do the recursive CTE this time ? ;-)

Comment: Thou shalt not request a recursive CTE in vain! ;) [Look!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10864507/939860) BTW, simplify `date_trunc('day', ser)::date` -> `ser::date`.

Comment: LOL. The extra date_trunc was indeed lazyness (ddkpppp+ search&& replace). I'll edit it down.

Comment: very nice!  keep forgetting how sweet these CTE's can be.  would really like to find a collection of about 20-30 CTE's to read so they would become more ingrained in my thinking.

Comment: @ccyoung: Such a collection is right here: List of recent answers with CTEs: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[postgresql]%20is%3aanswer%20cte%20with. The heart of the magic here is `generate_series()`, though. You could do the same with a subquery.

Comment: If I find that professional help for chronic CTEism, you'll be the first to know! ;) BTW, I couldn't resist, took the bait and added another version to my answer. :) The nested CTE can be serialized. You can put plain CTE in a `WITH RECURSIVE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is more than a matter of taste.  The performance of the query depends on the method.

As a first approximation, the functions should be faster.  They don't require joins, doing the read in a single table scan.

However, a good optimizer could make effective use of a lookup table.  It would know the distribution of the target values.  And, an in memory join could be quite fast.

As a database design, I think having a calendar table is very useful.  Some information such as holidays just isn't going to work as a function.  However, for most ad hoc queries the date functions are fine.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Your expression:

> ... between '2012-1-1' and '2011-12-31'

doesn't work. Basic [`BETWEEN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparison.html) requires the left argument to be less than or equal to the right argument. Would have to be:

```
... BETWEEN SYMMETRIC '2012-1-1' and '2011-12-31'
```

Or it's just a typo and you mean something like:

```
... BETWEEN '2011-1-1' and '2011-12-31'
```

It's unclear to me, what your queries are supposed to retrieve. I'll *assume* you want all weeks (Monday to Sunday) that start in 2011 for the rest of this answer. This expression generates exactly that in less than a microsecond on modern hardware (works for any year):

```
SELECT generate_series(
        date_trunc('week','2010-12-31'::date) + interval '7d'
       ,date_trunc('week','2011-12-31'::date) + interval '6d'
       , '1d')::date
```

*Note that the [ISO 8601 definition](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) of the "first week of a year is slightly different.

**2.** Your second query does not work at all. No `GROUP BY`?

**3.** The question you link to did not deal with PostgreSQL, which has outstanding date / timestamp support. And it has [**`generate_series()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) which can obviate the need for a separate "days" table in most cases - as demonstrated above. Your query would look like this:

*In the meantime [@wildplasser provided an example query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10864424/939860) that was supposed to go here.*

By popular* demand, a recursive CTE version - which is actually not that far from being a serious alternative!
<sub>* and by "popular" I mean [@wildplasser's very serious request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859504/in-sql-calculating-date-parts-versus-date-lookup-table-in-group-queries/10864424#comment14154197_10864424).</sub>

```
WITH RECURSIVE days AS (
    SELECT '2011-01-01'::date  AS dd
          ,date_trunc('week', '2011-01-01'::date )::date AS wk

    UNION ALL
    SELECT dd + 1
          ,date_trunc('week', dd + 1)::date AS wk
    FROM   days
    WHERE  dd < '2011-12-31'::date
    )
SELECT d.wk
      ,count(*) AS sale_ct
      ,sum(s.sale_amt) AS sale_amt
FROM days d
JOIN sale s ON s.tran_dt = d.dd
-- WHERE d.wk between '2011-01-01' and '2011-12-31'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Could also be written as ([compare to @wildplasser's version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10864424/939860)):

```
WITH RECURSIVE d AS (
    SELECT '2011-01-01'::date AS dd
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dd + 1 FROM d WHERE dd < '2011-12-31'::date
    ), days AS (
    SELECT dd, date_trunc('week', dd + 1)::date AS wk
    FROM d
    )
SELECT ...
```

**4.** If performance is of the essence, just make sure, that you do not apply functions or calculations to the values of your table. This prohibits the use of **indexes** and is generally very slow, because every row has to be processed. That's why your first query is going to suck with big table. When ever possible, apply calculations to the values you filter with, instead.

[**Indexes on expressions**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-expressional.html) are one way around this. If you had an index like

```
CREATE INDEX sale_tran_dt_week_idx ON sale (date_trunc('week', tran_dt)::date);
```

.. your first query could be very fast again - at some cost for write operations for index maintenance.

Comment: 1) thanks.  2) sorry about the typos and missing `group by` - fixed.  3) your reason #4 is the reason I felt the days table would be more efficient.  4) have you considered professional help in regard to this unnatural desire to write CTE's?

Comment: @ccyoung: You think there's a cure for chronic CTEtis? Well, there's always hope. :)

Comment: You could even use a nested CTE, avoiding the duplicate date_trunc(;)

Comment: @wildplasser: I won't take the bait! (And `date_trunc()` is only executed once per row anyway.)

Comment: Ok, than I'll do it. But I'll have to borrow your code for that.

Comment: @wildplasser: It is given freely. :)

Comment: It appears you found no cure. I don't like the "chained" CTE, since it exposes both CTE's to the outer scope. With the nested version only the outermost CTE is visible to the main query. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @wildplasser: That's how it is - so the nested CTE has its merits. I found it worth mentioning that a `WITH RECURSIVE` processes non-recursive CTEs just as well.